# Dual Monitor + Virtual Desktop software (plus for cube)

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I've recently purchased another monitor, my first one being a TV and being much larger. I now sit at a desk and use my shiny new 24" LED more often, but I like to extend the desktop into the TV. The problem presented with this is to save power and the longevity of my 47" VIZIO, I try to keep it off when possible.

What I'm seeking sounds very simple - If any of you have ever used Compiz or Deskspace (Yod'm) - You'll know what im referring to when I talk about a "cube."

The most important functionality I'm looking for is the ability to scroll desktop contents between both displays and virtual desktops.

Deskspace does and excellent job of presenting an attractive cube, but it creates a separate cube and virtual desktop space for the second extended monitor (now the TV) - Again, what I'm looking to do is scroll between virtual desktops, by passing through both monitors. The net effect of this functionality would allow me to scroll the contents of the extended monitor to the first monitor should a window get caught there without having to turn on the TV.

So imagine the horizontal portion of a cube as being actual real monitors - is there anything that allows one to rotate desktops between displays?

Answer (score 1):

On windows 7 you should be able to move a window using the windows key + the arrow keys when the window is selected like when you first open it. You'll probably have to hit the arrow key twice with the windows key down. I know its not quite what you asked for but its simple and already there, built in to windows 7.

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up using, though it's a less elegant solution than the one I was looking for. But as you said, it's built-in.